# How to make a glass effect?

Tags: css, styles

I'm trying to do something like this. (http://prnt.sc/f58ksy)
but I don't know how to make this glass effect, I tried to change the opacity but it didn't work. My code:

```
        .Head {
   position: absolute;
   top:200px;
   margin-left: 20%;
   color:white;
   background-color: #2acec3;
   margin-left: 8%;
   font-size: 400%;
   font-family: Calibri,Candara,Segoe,Segoe UI,Optima,Arial,sans-serif;
   opacity: 0.7;
   display: block;
}

.ParaPlanes {
   position: absolute;
   top:220px;
   margin-left: 20%;
   color:white;
   background-color: #2acec3;
   margin-left: 8%;
   font-size: 400%;
   font-family: Calibri,Candara,Segoe,Segoe UI,Optima,Arial,sans-serif;
   opacity: 0.7;
   display: block;
}
```

My result: http://prntscr.com/f58njn

Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The opacity property changes the transparency of it's child elements too...
Try -

```
background-color:rgba(red, green, blue, opacity ( decimal b/w 0 to 1))
```

Example -

```
#justadiv {
     background-color : rgba(24, 180, 140, 0.5);
}
```

The RGB values must be greater than 0 and less than 255.
Thanks !

Comment: Thanks for your support. I tried your idea and it looks like this: http://prntscr.com/f58r8a

Comment: @MadCatz... You need to remove the opacity property completely.

Comment: You need to have a pictorial background in order to see it work... A solid background would only change it's color. Can you please update the changes to the post ? thanks

Comment: Thank you my friend! :-)